# how can I route dns requests to ec2 load balancer?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, cname-record

I have a domain aaa01.ns01.info and it currently has 2 IPs setup a A records to use as round robin DNS.
I have setup an Ec2 load balancer at VPNLB-blahblahblah.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

How do I route requests to aaa01.ns01.info to the load balancer?
I tried a cname entry but it's not working.

Comment: CNAME should be fine, but alias records are preferred. What does "not working" actually mean?

Comment: cname is the right answer.. if the ELB is new enough give it some time before whatever resolver you are using can query it. I've seen some take an hour to show up on large corp resolvers

Comment: do I need to remove existing A records before adding a cname?